# Finding the limit of exponential looking sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_n = \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \bigg)^{-n} $

I am trying to make this look like the exponential, but to not avail. Probably the limit of such a sequence does not exist?

Comment: Does it help to notice that your expression is equal to $((1+\frac{1}{n})^n)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$, 
then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} = \frac{1}{e}$.